# vigenere cipher using oracle query

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am encrypting a column(Having primary key constraint)
in a table  by using below query in oracle. But for some data i am facing issues. I am proving my use case below.

**Query getting used:**

```
select regexp_replace(max(sys_connect_by_path(cy,'-')),'-','') plaintext
from (select row_number() over (order by L) rn, cy  from 
(select chr(mod(ascii(substr(p,level,1)) + 
        ascii(substr(k,decode(mod(level,length(k)),0,length(k),
        mod(level,length(k))),1))-130,26) + 65) cy
      ,level L
from (
select (p_in_cyphertext) p
       ,regexp_replace(key,' ') K
       from dual
       )
connect by level <= length(p)))
 connect by rn = prior rn + 1
 start with rn = 1;
```

**Input1:**
  p_in_cyphertext = 'N2N OLXQDIC FFP'
  key = 'A2f78C85798CFF3DFC74FE7014764C92'

**Output1**:
  N=S0FNOE:A:

**Input2**
 p_in_cyphertext = 'NLN OLXQDIC FFP'
 key = 'A2f78C85798CFF3DFC74FE7014764C92'

**Output2:**
N=S0FNOE:A:

Both the values are getting encrypted to same thing and hence i am getting unique constraint voilated error .
 This is happening because mod function for values 2 and L are returning same output: -4.

Can someone help me to improve this algorithm.

Comment: What is the (ASCII) range of the glyphs in your alphabet?  Is it 0 - z ( decimal 48 -> 122 ) ?

Comment: @stefan my alphabets can be anything that comes in UTF-8 Character set